# Changing content according to selected option in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, viewmodel, contentpresenter

I'm interested in creating an app that displays some buttons and changes a viewport according to the selected button. The viewport in my app is a `ContentControl` and I thought of changing its content whenever a button is clicked. However, I believe there's a better approach, by perhaps injecting the ViewModels of each of the Views I want to present to the `ContentControl` and styling them using `DataTemplates` (Since I want to avoid having a grid with many controls and just setting their `Visibility` property whenever I want to show a particular view). Which of the approaches seems better to you? Do you have a different approach for this?

The view should be something similar to this:
[image: General application UI design]

Thanks!

Comment: How are you changing the content at the moment?

Comment: "My question is - do you know of another, better approach for this?" - to answer this question we need to see your code )

Comment: I usually have an `ObservableCollection` of the ViewModel objects that I display using an `ItemsControl` that has a `Button` for the `ItemTemplate`, and bind a `ContentControl.Content` to the `SelectedItem`. You can see an example of such code [on my blog](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/navigation-with-mvvm-2/)

Comment: I didn't start to write it yet. It's just the first approach I thought of. I want to make sure I'm in the right direction before I write my code.

Comment: "better approach" is wide open question and it's against StackOverflow rules.

Comment: Sorry for that, HichemC. I'll try to follow StackOverflow's rules better next time. I'll rephrase

Comment: @JonathanPerry: From WPF point of view, your functionality can be achieved better using PRISM (MVVM pattern) framework. Where you can create one shell (basic or main screen) divide it into regions, create views, make them interact, based on selecting in one view, you can change UI (basically loading the related view in the region.)

Comment: @Rachel - Thanks! I think I'll go with your approach! ;) Nice blog btw

Comment: @PriyankThakkar - Thanks for the info, I'm not familiar with PRISM, but I'm sure going to have a look at that approach too

Comment: @JonathanPerry Thanks :) I've expanded that comment into an answer for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually have a ViewModel behind the window which contains:

- `ObservableCollection<IViewModel> AvailableViewModels`
- `IViewModel SelectedViewModel`
- `ICommand SetCurrentViewModelCommand`

I display the `AvailableViewModels` using an `ItemsControl`, which has its `ItemTemplate` set to a `Button`. The `Button.Command` is bound to the `SetCurrentViewModelCommand`, and it passes the current data item from the `AvailableViewModels` collection in through the `CommandParameter`

To display the content area, I use a `ContentControl` with `ContentControl.Content` bound to `SelectedViewModel`, and `DataTemplates` get used to tell WPF how to render each ViewModel.

The end result is my XAML looks something like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModelA}">
        <local:ViewA />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModelB}">
        <local:ViewB />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<DockPanel>
    <Border DockPanel.Dock="Left" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableViewModels}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Content="{Binding Name}"
                            Command="{Binding DataContext.SetCurrentViewModelCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding }"
                            Margin="2,5"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Border>

    <ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedViewModel}" />
</DockPanel>
```

You can view an example of the full code used for such a setup [on my blog](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/navigation-with-mvvm-2/)

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thanks Rachel!

Comment: @JonathanPerry Sorry, the `RelayCommand` is a custom class, not the one used by MVVM Light. The code for it is posted in the [Simple MVVM example blog post](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/simplemvvmexample/) (I was trying to keep 3rd party libraries out of my examples)

Comment: Thanks, found it also on MVVM light (it has a `RelayCommand` and `RelayCommand<T>` class that can be used with your example.